# Generalized Target Sum Problem

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given an integer x and an unsorted array of integers, describe an algorithm to
determine whether two of the numbers add up to x. (In this case, hash tables not allowed).
**Solution is:**

Sort the array. Then, keep track of two pointers in the array, one at
the beginning and one at the end. Whenever the sum of the current two integers is
less than x, move the first pointer forwards, and whenever the sum is greater than x,
move the second pointer backwards. If you cannot find two numbers that add to x
before one of the pointers meet, then there is no pair of integers that sum to x. This
solution takes O(n log n) time because we sort the numbers.

Can we have generalized solution for `k` integers. Say above problem is for `k=2`. I want now find `3` integer with `target sum` and so on.

Comment: Do you want a generalization with k pointers or can we use other structures?

Comment: Any other structure or algorithm will do.

Comment: This is called the subset-sum problem btw

Comment: @Hunter: For fixed k < n, this is a little different than subset-sum... right?

Comment: @Patrick A little different yes, the subset-sum problem has a full solution for all n integers. But, for any k < n I imagine you could use the same algorithm to find the answer

Comment: @Hunter: Oh, I'm not arguing that a solution to subset-sum wouldn't solve this quite easily (just modify subset-sum to disregard solutions subsets of the wrong size). However, the real question is about how fast you can solve these kinds of problems... and you can do better than subset-sum for fixed k, as the OP himself demonstrates.

Comment: @Patrick, definitely O(n log n) is way faster than subset sum, I just mentioned it because he didn't list the problem name above.

Comment: @Hunter  - This is definitely not faster than the psuedo-polytime solution to subset sum in all cases.  The algorithms time is O(MAX_SUM*n) vs O(n^(k/2)).  For a dataset with large n and low target sum, this is *much* faster

Answer (score 2):

Just to place an upper bound on this... for fixed k, the problem is always in P (polynomial in terms of the size of the list of numbers, n, anyway) and can be solved by a simple O(n^k) algorithm: generate k-sets (there are C(n,k) of them) and check them. For the k=2 case, this corresponds to generating all n(n+1)/2 two-sets and checking them.

If we instead take k <= n, this problem is equivalent to the subset sum problem, hence NP-complete.

Note that these represent strict upper bounds on the complexity... for k = 2, you have found an O(n log n) algorithm, and the approach may generalize to higher k.

Edit2: removed some tighter bounds since it seems like my construction was wrong. Sorry for screwing up. Props to spinning_plate for keeping me honest.

Comment: If you recursively delved for that pair, it had to be less than or equal to the sum. Only if the pair causes the sum to be greater do you try moving the last pointer back... Otherwise, moving the lower one forward seems sufficient.

Comment: What about the case where k = 5 and [1,2,3,4,5.5,6] and the sum is 15.5?  I'm not understand how you keep track of which way to go when the sub-sums can be both greater and lesser.  Can you show some psuedo-code of the recursive function?

Comment: I will try to add some later, but the idea is simple: if the current sum < target, recurse; if succeeded, stop; else, increment low pointer. If current sum > target, decrement high pointer. Repeat until solution OR low pointer = high pointer. In other words, the decision of which pointer to change does not depend on lower levels of the recursion tree... The only way lower levels can affect upper levels is by terminating the computation altogether once any solution is found.

Comment: So, in my example, we start by chosing (1,6), and continue looking for the sum 9 on the array [2,3,4,5.5]. The sum is never too high at the top level of recursion, so 6 is always chosen and we dont find an answer?. What I'm getting at is that I think you're going to have to eventually enumerate all (n choose k) subsets, so I don't know if your bound holds.

Comment: Interesting. I'll take a look later and see if this is a problem and, if so, whether it can be fixed...

Comment: Yeah, so, I think you're completely right about the recursive thing not really working. The problem is that the outermost level never rejects the 6. I'll update my answer to reflect the fact that my tightest bounds are wrong. Good catch.

Comment: I think it's still an interesting idea.  You can still cut of some of the states if you know all the subproblems are over/under the total sum.  I tried implementing it to play around with the idea, see my answer if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use any data structures, you  can simply treat this as a [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) and keep track of how many numbers you have used in addition to the sum.

```
numbers = [xxx]
buckets = [[0,0] for x in range(MAX_SUM)]
buckets[0][0] = 1;
for number in numbers:
    for bucketi in range(MAX_SUM):
        if buckets[bucketi][0] == 1 and buckets[bucketi][1] < k: 
           buckets[bucketi+number][0] = 1;
           buckets[bucketi+number][1] = buckets[bucketi][1] + 1;
```

Here's also an attempt at what @Patrick was getting at, I'm not sure of the bound but it's an interesting idea.

```
def go_(numbers, range_bottom,range_top,sum_target,k,min_v,max_v,nums):
    min_v_,max_v_,res_ = go(numbers, range_bottom,range_top,sum_target-sum(nums),k)
    min_v = min(min_v,min_v_)
    max_v = max(max_v,max_v_)
    if len(res_) > 0:
        newres = [x for x in res_]
        newres = newres+nums
        return [0,0,newres]
    return [min_v,max_v,res_]

def go(numbers, range_bottom,range_top,sum_target,k):

    if sum_target==0 and k == 0:
        return [0,0,['-']];
    elif sum_target<0 or k==0 or range_bottom == range_top:
        return [sum_target,sum_target,[]]


    min_v = 666; max_v = -666;

    if range_top-range_bottom>1:
        min_v ,max_v, res_ = go_(numbers, range_bottom+1, range_top-1, sum_target,k-2,min_v,max_v,[numbers[range_bottom],numbers[range_top-1\
]])
        if len(res_):

            return [0,0,res_];

    if not ( min_v<0 and max_v<0 ):
        min_v ,max_v, res_ = go_(numbers, range_bottom+1, range_top, sum_target ,k,min_v,max_v ,[])
        if len(res_):


            return [0,0,res_];


    if not ( min_v>0 and max_v>0 ):
        min_v ,max_v, res_ = go_(numbers, range_bottom, range_top-1, sum_target,k,min_v,max_v,[])
        if len(res_):

            return [0,0,res_];

    return [min_v,max_v,res_]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am getting a feeling that this will get loads of downvotes, as I dont speak maths(or CS lingo for that matter), but I am just letting out my thoughts on how to extend your approach
I am assuming that

1. Distinct set of integers are required (no repetition)
2. Whenever sum=x I store the integers that satisfied sum=x and move on, so
       that I get all the tuples of integers satisfying sum=x

### Section A

**k = 3 and x = sum**

Sort the array in ascending order.
Place first_pointer on the first integer and second_pointer on the second integer (i.e. next to first pointer).
Put the third_pointer on the last integer.

1. Calculate sum=first_pointer + second_pointer + third_pointer.
2. if sum < x then second_pointer++ Repeat Step 1.
3. if sum > x then third_pointer-- Repeat Step 1.
4. Repeat Step 1 to 3 till second_pointer >= third_pointer i.e. the pointers meet.
5. first_pointer++; second_pointer=first_pointer+1; third_pointer=last integer i.e. shift the first_pointer by one step (on the right) and place second_pointer next to first pointer, return the third pointer to last integer.
6. Repeat Step 1 to 5, til on 5th step second_pointer=third_pointer.
7. If you reach till here, without finding any sum=x then there is no solution (I may be wrong here, but I dont see any other possibility.)

---

### Section B

**for k = 4 and x = sum**

Sort the array in ascending order.
Place the first two pointers as in **Section A**.
Put the third and fourth one on the last two integers, i.e. third pointer=second_last_integer and fourth_pointer=last_integer.

1. Similar to **Section A Step 1** sum=pointer(1st+2nd+3rd+4th)
2. Similar to **Section A Step 2**
3. (*This is different*)if sum > x then fourth_pointer--
4. Similar to **Section A Step 4**
5. (*now on its totally different*) I will divide this as 5.a and 5.b for clarity
   5.a This part is similar to **Section A** in the sense that you will shift the first and second pointer keeping them next to one another and repeating steps 1 to 4 of **Section B**
   5.b If you did not find the sum yet fourth_pointer--; third_pointer=fourth_pointer-1 and repeat Steps 1 to 4 **and 5.a**
6. Repeat 5.b till second_pointer=third_pointer.

If you have reached till here without any sum=x, then there is no solution //standard-disclaimer

---

### Section C

(I am really falling short screen space, as I cant see preview of what I am writing. So I will keep it short and leave it upto your imagination)
**for any k and x = sum**

Sort the array in ascending order.
Place first int(k/2) pointers in the beginning.
Place the rest k-int(k/2) pointers at the end.

1. Calculate sum = sigma(k).
2. if sum < x then pointer(int(k / 2))++. Repeat from Step 1.
3. if sum > x then pointer(k - int(k / 2))--. Repeat from Step 1.
4. Repeat from Step 1 till pointer(int(k / 2)) >= pointer(k - int(k / 2)).
5. Now take the [int(k / 2) - 1,int(k / 2),(k - int(k / 2)),(k - int(k / 2) + 1)] pointers and proceed similar to **Section B**.
6. Repeat above by shifting int(k / 2) - 2 to the right, then by shifting (k - int(k / 2) +  2) to the left.
7. Extend Step 6 till you shift all pointers < int(k / 2) so that they just overlap

### THE END

//phew !! wrote so much !!

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/sj7yGs4n) for pastebin, where you can read it without the scroll bars, I was not able to post for a long time, because SO thought I had lots of code in my post, but I did not indent it properly. And I sincerely hope that nobody asks me to calculate the order of my algorithm *fingers crossed*

Comment: @downvoter : I was expecting this, but care to enlighten me on the reasons??

Comment: @Sudhi: please check your Section A - it's unreadable. I understand your idea and it seems to make sense, but without complexity analysis and even clear algorithm it is completely useless.

Comment: the step 2 should read : 2. `if sum<x then second_pointer++` Repeat from Step 1. 3. if sum.... @ffriend : is it clear now? I am sorry, I do not have the appropriate expertise in algo analysis but I do believe that my algorithm is clear enough, which part of algo you did NOT understand?

Comment: @glenn-jackman : can you please re-edit my post?? Step 2 in Section A and in Section B are missing the complete `if sum<x then...` statements. I tried, but SO still complaints about not indenting my code :(

Comment: @sudhi, they were not missing. Once I remove the indent, they were being interpreted as HTML tags. I've rolled back my edit, you can fix it up if you like.

Comment: I have completely reformatted your text, returning all steps to their place. Please set spaces around "<" and ">" characters and everything will be ok. Now you algo makes sense, so +1.

Comment: BTW, complexity analysis for you algo is as follows: sorting of an array takes O(n*log n) (from Wikipedia). On steps 2 and 3 2nd and 3rd pointers will meet after they pass together n elements (n - 3, in fact, but it doesn't matter here), steps 5 and 6 say to repeat it all n times too, so so final number of steps is `(n * log(n)) + n * n` (sorting + steps[2, 3] * steps[5, 6]). Here it is! Complexity of your algo is `O(n * log(n)) + n * n)`. Only one more moment: `n * log(n)` is smaller than `n * n`, so this element may be omitted and final complexity is just `O(n * n)` or `O(n ^ 2)`.

Comment: @ffriend : thank you so much for taking the pains to format my post! I will keep in mind to keep spaces around < , > . As for the complexity analysis, well its still a little bit of rocket science to me, but looking at the final order (and going through few wiki pages), it looks pretty good to me :) . Thanks again ! I wonder if someone else will ever understand my algo and find it interesting. *sigh*